# HTML5 Sortable - dragging item disappears in Internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, opacity, jquery-ui-sortable

**In Internet Explorer 9**, when I drag items in [this example](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/#sortable2) of the [jQuery HTML5 Sortable plugin](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable), the dragging item disappears, even though [it states](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/#features) that it supports IE 5.5+. It looks like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem, works fine in my IE9

Comment: Are you on Windows7? Could you share a screenshot?

Comment: I have Win7 yes, here's the [screenshot](http://imageshack.us/a/img337/3199/bildschirmfoto20120919u.png), as you can see I switched item 2 with 3 and 5 with 2.

Comment: Just wondering: do you drag & drop the element and it just disappears or is it disturbing to you that an element is not directly visible while dragging?

Comment: The latter. While dragging, the element I move looks fully transparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably fix it easily by switching to jQuery UI - the official UI library for jQuery!

I've used the [drag and drop component](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) numerous times and have never noticed any disappearing issues in IE.

Of course, it *could* be something to do you your current HTML/CSS, or some other conflicting script. Switching out to another plugin would help demonstrate whether it was your code, or the plugin that was at fault.

EDIT:

Problem on the actual demo site for the plugin...Have retained above comment as this is still a valid debugging path in situations like this where it *is* (or at least could be) custom code causing a problem...

Comment: The problem can't be in my code since the example above is in developer's site.

Comment: Ha ha, of course. Must be the plugin then! Switch it out for something that definitely works ;)

Comment: I ended up switching to the official jQuery UI Sortable. It was pretty straightforward and solved the original problem.